# NSCFStringというクラスの扱いを知りたい

Tags: swift, ios8, twitter

以下のようにしてACAccountStoreからTwitterのアカウント情報を配列で取得できました。

```
    let accountStore = ACAccountStore();
    let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter);
    accounts = accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(twitterAccountType);
```

取得したアカウント情報からTwitterのuser_idを取得したところNSCFStringというクラスのオブジェクトが返されているようでした。

```
    for ac in accounts {
        println(ac.username)
        println(ac.valueForKeyPath("properties.user_id")!) // <- ここ
    }
```

Stringにキャストすればよいのですが、そもそもNSCFStringというのがよくわからず。。
通常、どのようにキャストするのが良いとかありましたらご教示お願いしたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「クラスクラスタ Objective-C」でネット検索すると、あなたが知りたい情報を得られます。
Swiftは、Objective-Cから、クラスクラスタという機構も継承しているはず。

Comment: ありがとうございます。クラスクラスタ調べてみました。
NSStringは抽象クラスで実際には最適な実装クラスが選択されて利用されているというような挙動だということは理解できました。
http://hmdt.jp/blog/?p=1143

Answer (score 1):

__NSCFStringはNSStringの派生クラスですのでキャストは不要です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
例えばなのですが、質問のようにuseridを取得して、

    var userid = ac.valueForKeyPath("properties.user_id")
    "aaaa" + userid // これはダメ
    "aaaa \(userid)" // これならOK

といった感じなのですが、この辺が良く理解できませんでした。
こういった使い方をしたい場合にどうするのが良さそうでしょうか。。

Comment: Swiftでは、+演算子で結合できるのは、文字列どおし。文字列と数値などの結合には、「埋め込み」という方法をとります。    
`"abcd" + "efgh" // abcdefgh`　`"abcd\(1234)" // abcd1234`